# Fill Area between Lines with color - Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have series of lines, and I need to color all the area beneath or between lines with a color.

For the sake of simplicity, I have created a snippet with closed lines.
In reality, i have a program that draws many lines (like a stock market graph) , and I need to color all the area below the graph. see also the screenshot.

would appreciate any help or even new approach that maybe I need to take.

[image]

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>My first three.js app</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 500);

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        function createLine(startX,startY,endX,endY) {
            const geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(startX, startY, 0));
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(endX, endY, 0));
            const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
                color: 0xffffff
            });
            return new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
        }
        scene.add(createLine(0,0,1,0));
        scene.add(createLine(1,0,1,1));
        scene.add(createLine(1,1,0,1));
        scene.add(createLine(0,1,0,0));

        camera.position.z = 5;

        var animate = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        animate();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with three.js, but in order to color a graph like you want, I would guess you need to draw one big shape, not a lot of separate lines. Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: don't know. that's the question. will be glad if you try and come up with solution :)   I can of course "close" the graph with additional lines. that's why i attached the simple snippet which is 4 closed lines. to keep things simple.

Comment: As an option, you can use `THREE.PlaneGeometry()` and change its upper vertices.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`THREE.Shape`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/extras/core/Shape) and [`THREE.ShapeGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/ShapeGeometry) to draw a filled polygon by [`THREE.Mesh`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/Mesh):

```
function createPolygon( poly ) {
    var shape = new THREE.Shape();
    shape.moveTo( poly[0][0], poly[0][1] );
    for (var i = 1; i < poly.length; ++ i)
        shape.lineTo( poly[i][0], poly[i][1] );
    shape.lineTo( poly[0][0], poly[0][1] );

    var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( shape );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
        color: 0x800000
    } );
    return new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
}

var poly = [[0,1],[0.25,0],[0.5,0.5],[0.75,0],[1,1]];
scene.add(createPolygon(poly))
```

See the example:

```js
var renderer, scene, camera, controls;

init();
animate();

function createLine(startX,startY,endX,endY) {
    const geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(startX, startY, 0));
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(endX, endY, 0));
    const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff
    });
    return new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
}

function createPolygon( poly ) {
  var shape = new THREE.Shape();
  shape.moveTo( poly[0][0], poly[0][1] );
  for (var i = 1; i < poly.length; ++ i)
    shape.lineTo( poly[i][0], poly[i][1] );
  shape.lineTo( poly[0][0], poly[0][1] );
    
  var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( shape );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
        color: 0x800000
    } );
    return new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
}

function init() {

    // renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    //camera.position.set( 20, 20, 20 );
    camera.position.z = 5;
    window.onresize = resize;

    var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xeeeeee, 0x888888, 1 );
      light.position.set( 0, 20, 0 );
      scene.add( light );
    
    var poly = [[0,1],[0.25,0],[0.5,0.5],[0.75,0],[1,1]];
    
    scene.add(createPolygon(poly))
    
    for (var i = 0; i < poly.length-1; ++i)
    {
        var i2 = i<poly.length-1 ? i+1 : 0 
        scene.add(createLine(poly[i][0],poly[i][1],poly[i2][0],poly[i2][1]));
    }
}

function resize() {
    
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.124/build/three.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

[image]

To fill it with colour, you have to use a geometry with faces (`THREE.Face3()`). To have it, you need to trialngulate a shape or to use an existing geometry, which fits to your needs, with some changes of its vertices.

Below, there is a very rough concept, using an existing geometry (`THREE.PlaneGeometry()`), which *colours the **area below the graph***. But keep in mind, that such approach is okay to use, when you need to show only positive or only negative values in one graph, otherwise, the result will look strange (or better to say, ugly).

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 2, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var points = [],
  pointCount = 21;
var plane, line;

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper( pointCount - 1, pointCount -1 ));

for (let i = 0; i < pointCount; i++) {
  points.push({
    initValue: THREE.Math.randFloat(-1, 1),
    amplitude: THREE.Math.randFloat(1, 2),
    speed: THREE.Math.randFloat(.5, 2)
  });
}

createGraph( pointCount );

function createGraph( pointCount ) {
  var planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(pointCount - 1, 1, pointCount - 1, 1);
  planeGeom.translate(0, .5, 0);

  plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: "red",
    wireframe: false,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: .75
  }));
  scene.add(plane);

  var lineGeom = new THREE.Geometry();
  for (let i = 0; i < plane.geometry.parameters.widthSegments + 1; i++) {
    lineGeom.vertices.push(planeGeom.vertices[i]); // share the upper points of the plane
  }
  line = new THREE.Line(lineGeom, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: "aqua"
  }));
  plane.add(line);
}


var time = 0;

render();

function render() {
  time = Date.now() * .001;
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  points.forEach( ( p, idx ) => {
    plane.geometry.vertices[idx].y = 2.5 + Math.sin( (time + p.initValue) * p.speed) * p.amplitude;  // the trick is that indices of upper vertices are from 0 to N consequently in row (r87),
    // thus we can assign the data from the `points` array to their Y-coordinates to form the graph
  });
  plane.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true; // the most important thing when you change coordiantes of vertices
  line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true; // the most important thing when you change coordiantes of vertices
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create 1 big shape taking into account the whole graph you want to fill. So, just like in your image but then include the axis.

Then you can fill the shape with any kind of material.

Here are some examples on the threejs website:

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=shape#webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=shape#webgl_geometry_shapes

You probably wont need to extrude like in those examples.